# Unexpected output in C program

Tags: c, relational-operators

I run the following C program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 5, y = 6, z = 3, i;
    i = y > x > z;
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

and get the output as `0`.
Again, when I run

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main() {
     int x = 5, y = 6, z = 3, i;
     i = y > x && x > z;
     printf("%d\n", i);
 }
```

I get output as `1`. Can anyone explain the logic behind this?

Comment: `6 > 5 == 1`-> `1 > 3 == 0`

Comment: If you understand how these operators work, it should be pretty self-explanatory. The only thing that might be somewhat subtle here is operator associativity, where the relational operators guarantee left-to-right. That is, the expression is guaranteed to be equivalent to `(y > x) > z`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i = y > x > z;
```

In first example, associativity of `>` operator **left to right**, So, First parsed `y > x` and gives boolean result.

```
y > x = 6 > 5 = True
```

then,

```
1(True) > 3 = False
```

So, output `0`.

**In Second,**

```
i = y > x && x > z;
```

`>` operator **higher precedence** then `&&` operator. So, first parsed `y > x` and if condition **True**, then check `x > z`.

Comment: Nit-pick: operator precedence and associativity dictate the order in which the expression is _parsed_, not evaluated. The order of evaluation is unspecified. That is, given `y() > x() > z()`, you cannot know the order in which the functions are executed. Only that the results from y() and x() are used with `>` before the result of that is compared with the result from z().

Comment: @Lundin Thanks!!, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 10):

Relational operators are associated from [left to right](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). Therefore `i = y > x > z;` will be parsed as

```
i = ( (y > x) > z ) => ( (6 > 5) > 3 ) => ( 1 > 3 ) => 0
```

and `i = y > x && x > z;` will be parsed as

```
i = (y > x) && (x > z) => (6 > 5) && (5 > 3) => 1 && 1 => 1
```

That said, in C `y > x > z` doesn't check if `x` is greater than `z` and less than `y`. But `y > x && x > z` does.

---

Note that relational operators return either `0` or `1` depending if the relation between the operands are `false` or `true`.

Comment: I was just gonna post the same thing. I'm too slow at typing

Comment: The answer could be improved by: Mentioning that operator associativity  is left to right for `>`. Also mention/link the operator precedence/associativity table so that OP can learn how to find the same information for other operators.